# How to restrict parameter types in generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, methods

Say I have 3 classes: `A`,`B` and `C`. Each of these class have a `GetValue()` method, which returns an `int`. I want to create this method:

```
int GetTotalValue<T,R>(T c1, R c2)
{
  return c1.GetValue() + c2.GetValue()
}
```

Obviously, this won't work. As not all parameter types have a `GetValue()` method. So how do I restrict the parameter types `T` and `R`, so they have to have a `GetValue()` method (that returns an `int`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have all three implement an interface that contains the `GetValue` method and constrain the method to using just those types.

```
public interface IGetValue
{
    int GetValue();
}

public class A : IGetValue  // Same for B and C
{
    ...
}
```

Then finally:

```
int GetTotalValue<T,R>(T c1, R c2) where T : IGetValue, R : IGetValue
{
    return c1.GetValue() + c2.GetValue();
}
```

**UPDATE**

As Alex points out in him comment, this method doesn't need to be generic though, it can be rewritten:

```
int GetTotalValue(IGetValue c1, IGetValue c2)
{
    return c1.GetValue() + c2.GetValue();
}
```

Comment: You may want to add to your answer, that with this generic constraint, for the sample method used in OPs question, a generic method does not make sense. He could simply use `int GetTotalValue(IGetValue c1, IGetValue c2)`.

Comment: @Alex, very good point. I've updated the answer to reflect that.